# как вернуться на главный экран с помощью MDToolbar?

Tags: python, kivy

у меня есть два Screen. В первом нажимая на кнопку нас переносит на другой Screen, как я могу вернутся со второго Screen на первый используя MDToolbar? ( желательно с иконкой " назад"),( можно ли тоже самое сделать только используя свайп по экрану ?)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

KV = """
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

ScreenManager: 
    Screen:
        name: 'Screen one'  # имя экрана
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical' 

            MDToolbar:
                title: "eBook"
                elevation: 10
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback()]]
                pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(45)
                MDFlatButton: 
                    text: 'Chosen subject' 
                    size_hint: 1, 1 
                    on_press:
                        root.current = 'Chosen subject'  # смена экрана



    Screen:
        name: 'Chosen subject'  # имя экрана
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical' 
            MDToolbar:
                title: "eBook"
                elevation: 10
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback()]]
                pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color



    """


class HelloWorld(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


HelloWorld().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подержи мое пиво...

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "eBook"
        elevation: 10
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]

    Carousel:
        id: carousel
        on_current_slide: app.on_current_slide(*args)

        Screen:
            name: "screen 1"

            MDFlatButton: 
                text: 'Screen 1' 
                on_release: carousel.load_next()
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

        Screen:
            name: "screen 2"

            MDFlatButton: 
                text: 'Screen 2' 
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}            
"""


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_current_slide(self, instance_carousel, instance_screen):
        if instance_screen.name == "screen 2":
            self.root.ids.toolbar.left_action_items = [["arrow-left", lambda x: self.set_previous_screen()]]
        else:
            self.set_toolbar_button()

    def set_toolbar_button(self):
        self.root.ids.toolbar.left_action_items = [["menu", lambda x: x]]

    def set_previous_screen(self):
        self.root.ids.carousel.load_previous()
        self.set_toolbar_button()


Test().run()
```

Comment: спасибо большое )))

Comment: здравствуйте , а как реализовать MDNavigationDrawer?

Comment: https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki/Components-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: Еще раз здравствуйте, простите но я так и не смог разобраться как взаимодействует ваш код и  MDNavigationDrawer, я создал новый  вопрос и буду очень благодарен если поможете новичку в этом деле https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106060/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-mdnavigationdrawer

Comment: я пробовал использовать loop как в документах что бы при прокрутки начальной назад показывалась последния , и наоборот , но так и не получилось, можете подсказать по этому поводу ?